# Configurar o Menu do WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu, plugin-wordpress

Olá, tenho um menu no wordpress, e gostaria que ele tivesse uns subMenus de usuário.
Atualmente ja tenho esse SUBMENU porem na barra do WP da pagina como mostra a img a seguir
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas eu gostaria que ele ficasse junto com o menu do site, ou seja, sem aparecer essa barra superior do WordPress.
Gostaria que ela ficasse aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém poderia me ajudar com isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O plugin [User Menus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-menus/) faz exatamente isso que você busca, ele oferece mais controle sobre o menu de navegação, permitindo que você aplique controles de visibilidade aos itens do menu, por exemplo, quem pode ver cada item do menu (todos, usuários desconectados, usuários conectados, funções de usuário específicas).